# Возврат в нужное место списка при пагинации

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть список элементов с ajax пагинацией, кнопка "показать еще" подгружает еще несколько элементов списка. Заходим на детальную страницу элемента, например, на третьей подгруженной странице списка. Нажимаем кнопку назад - нужно сфокусироваться в списке на этом элементе т.е. подгрузить 2 страницы и прокрутить до этого элемента.

---

Вопрос - как лучше это реализовать?

1. Сохранять в куках например количество загруженных страниц или id элемента, при возврате назад брать из куков эту инфу и пытаться найти элемент.
2. При подгрузке страниц менять урл.
   Есть какойто стандартный способ?

Comment: Храните количество страниц и id элемента в куках. Ухищрения с url работать не будут.

Comment: Так и сделал, только сохранил в сессии. При клике на элемент  (переходе на детальную) сохранил, Если загружается страница со списком - достаю эту переменную. Единственное еще пришлось очищать переменную в сессии если пользователь перешел на другую страницу (через меню например) Иначе когда зашел бы опять в каталог, подгрузились бы страницы которые не нужны.
Решение от Bookin интересное, попробую (сейчас надо было сделать оперативно)
Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `window.history` для изменения url браузера, при нажатии на пагинацию меняете url:

```
history.pushState({page:3}, "page 3", "page3.html");
```

Url измениться на `http://somesite.com/page3.html`. После того как нажмут кнопку назад, браузер вернет на страницу `http://somesite.com/page3.html`, и вызовет событие `popstate`:

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};
```

В `event.state` будет храниться обьект переданный в `pushState` - `{page:3}`, вы можете получить номер страницы, и загрузить недостающие части.

Так же можете использовать `window.localStorage`, схема примерно та же, при пагинации сохранять номер страницы в `window.localStorage`, при возвращении считывать номер страницы и загружать что вам необходимо.
Так же можете посмотреть в сторону сессий.